# Consultation and deliberation with select and distinct query

Tags: sql

i have this table:

```
sCount  |  Name  |  Flag
=========================
 1         | AAA     |  Y
 1         | BBB     |  N
 1         | BBB     |  Y
 1         | CCC     |  N
```

i need to count the same Name and if there is N or F on Flag, i need to show only Y

the table will looks like this:

```
sCount  |  Name  |  Flag
=========================
 1         | AAA     |  Y
 2         | BBB     |  Y
 1         | CCC     |  N
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `max()`:

```
select sum(sCount) as sCount, Name, max(Flag) as flag
from t
group by sCount, Name;
```

This uses the fact that "Y" is greater than "N".